# Does order matter when drawing player cards? (Efficient to Sequence + Epidemic)

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

One of the positive disease mutations in Pandemic: Legacy is Efficient to Sequence.  A disease with this mutation is cured immediately when a player discards the correct number of cards.  The rules note that this doesn't have to occur on your own turn.  (For example, another player can, on his turn, give you the last card, and you can immediately cure the disease if you are at a research station or don't need to be.)

How does this interact with drawing player cards at the end of the turn?  If one of the cards you draw is the last card you need then clearly you can cure the disease -- if you can do it on someone else's turn then you can do it during the draw phase of your own turn too.  But what happens if you draw the last card you need and an Epidemic?  There are three possibilities:

- cure the disease first
- resolve the epidemic first
- process the cards in the order drawn

The order matters if there are currently no cubes of that color on the board -- curing the disease would also eradicate it, so the epidemic city wouldn't gain cubes if of that color.  (I realize this is a corner case, but the question has come up in our group.)

Answer (score 5):

Order does not matter; you draw both cards at the same time. And if either is an Epidemic, you must resolve it first before curing a disease.

From the [FAQ](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1470601/compiled-faq-spoilers-hidden-each-month-hidden-sep)

> If we have the 2nd beneficial mutation, exactly when can we discover the cure?
>
> > You can do it out of turn, **but you can’t so it halfway through an epidemic.** It’s also worth noting when drawing player cards, you’ll have to discard down to hand size before curing.

Comment: The part you quoted from the FAQ says you can't do it *during* an epidemic, but just after you've drawn the two cards you haven't yet started the epidemic.  Does drawing the card set the epidemic in motion immediately?  (I'm not trying to argue for a particular position; I'm just trying to resolve an apparent ambiguity before we next play.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Although I agree "halfway through" is a strange choice of words, I can't think of a situation where you'd want to or need to do it after having resolved some of the epidemic, but before you finished resolving it. So I took "halfway through" as "after drawing the epidemic card but before completely resolving the epidemic".

Comment: I could imagine someone (now) having enough cards to cure a disease, but one of them has a sticker he'd like to use so he gambles that somebody'll pass him another card for the cure -- but then the epidemic city is that color and will set outbreaks in motion, so maybe he wants to try the cure now.  That would count as "halfway through".  It's also an extreme edge case.

Answer (score 1):

We just started playing Season 2 and I see that the rules there have clarified what happens in the draw phase.  While this doesn't directly answer the question about Season 1, it might show designer intent.  The [Season 2 rules](https://images-cdn.zmangames.com/us-east-1/filer_public/38/ec/38ec25b0-821b-4c2e-b925-27c4a4038acd/pandemic_legacy_season_2_rules.pdf) (page 13) say this about drawing cards:

> After doing 4 actions, draw the top 2 cards together from the Player deck. [...] If your draws include any Epidemic cards, do not add them to your hand (and do not draw replacement cards for them). Instead, immediately do the following in order:

In Season 2, the card you draw along with an epidemic does not become part of your hand until after you resolve the epidemic.  If it's not in your hand, you can't use it.  If we apply that reasoning to Season 1, then the city card drawn with the epidemic isn't part of your hand and thus is not available to be discarded.

Comment: While Pandemic Legacy Season 2 is a different game (with different rules), identical verbage exists for the corresponding step of the player's turn in the Season 1 rules (on page 11).

Comment: @KitsuneZeta oh!  We must have missed that when we were playing season 1.  Thanks.